# amCharts random colors

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have a [Stacked Column Chart](http://jsfiddle.net/TZg4C/2/), with 13 graphs. In the used [theme](http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js) 11 colors are defined. Is there a way to avoid the color of 12th and 13th graph to be chosen randomly after every instantiation, without specifying the `color` property of the `graph`?

Comment: @Bny 
can you answer 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035747/display-of-stacked-column-chart-amcharts-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add more colors to the pool

```
http://jsfiddle.net/maertz/LLWft/
```

or define a specific color within the dataProvider

```
http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#colorField
```

Comment: I tried the second solution, http://jsfiddle.net/K2AZW/. Here I defined the colorField, lineColorField and fillColorsField. In the chart only the bullets are colored after the color of the dataProvider nor the legend (an other example for legend coloring: http://jsfiddle.net/6hFS7/).

Comment: unfortunately this is a missbehaviour which will be fixed within the next release, thanks for figuring this out

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to avoid this, just by adding more colors.

Comment: This is not true, you can set the colors list via .colors property of the AmCoordinateChart (parent object of AmChart): http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmCoordinateChart#colors